# Location Keep Jumping around in google map

Tags: android, google-maps

I am facing an issue in actual ride distance tracking within the app . The issue is onLocationChanged sending wrong locations suddenly and jumping between here and there and due to this distance is calculating wrong. I think it could be the network fluctuation issue because it is working fine with stable network connection. I am attaching the screenshot. Any handling of this use case. Thanks in advance.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixIsW.png)

Comment: Please provide MCVE - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Have you tried to apply [Snap to roads](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap) using Roads API?